# How to trim a video by 4 fragments to 4 seconds using the PHP-FFMpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

How to trim a video using the **PHP-FFMpeg**?
I need to implement the following **FFMpeg** command:

```
ffmpeg -i 7207783801bb.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=start=10:end=11,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=20:end=21,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; \
  [a][b]concat[c]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=30:end=31,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=40:end=41,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[f]; \
   [d][f]concat[g]; \
 [c][g]concat[out1]" -map [out1] 7207783801bbout.mp4
```

When I use the following code:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('7207783801bb.mpg');
$video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(11));
$video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(20), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(21));
$video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(30), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(31));
$video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(40), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(41));
$video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), '7207783801bbout.mp4');
```

then I get only 40 seconds of video.
And I need to get 10-11, 20-21, 30-31, 40-41 seconds using the **PHP-FFMpeg**. Only 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this case FFMpeg\Media\AdvancedMedia can be used

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->openAdvanced(['7207783801bb.mp4']);
$video->filters()
    ->custom('[0:v]', 'trim=start=10:end=11,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS', '[a]')
    ->custom('[0:v]', 'trim=start=20:end=21,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS', '[b]')
    ->custom('[a][b]', 'concat', '[c]')
    ->custom('[0:v]', 'trim=start=30:end=31,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS', '[d]')
    ->custom('[0:v]', 'trim=start=40:end=41,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS', '[f]')
    ->custom('[d][f]', 'concat', '[g]')
    ->custom('[c][g]', 'concat', '[out1]')
;
$video
    ->map(['[out1]'], new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), '7207783801bbout.mp4')
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual pages](https://packagist.org/packages/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg)

> **Clip**
>
> The clip filter takes two
> parameters:
>
> $start, an instance of FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode, specifies the start
> point of the clip
>
> **$duration, optional, an instance of FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode, specifies the duration of the clip**

(Emphasis mine)

So your second parameter needs to be 1 instead of (for example) 11 as it is the clip duration...

```
$video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10),
       FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(1));
```